# Let A and B be n*n matrices such that trace(A)<0<trace(B).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let A and B $n\times n$ such that trace(A)$\lt0\lt$trace(B).

Then, $f(t)=1-det(e^{tA+(1-t)B})$ has

1) infinitely many zeros in $0\lt t\lt1$

2) at least one zero in $\Bbb R$

3) no zeros

4) either no zeros or infinitely many zeros in $\Bbb R$.

According to my knowledge determinant is defined for square matrices not for exponential functions. So, I think something is wrong in the question. If this question is correct then how can I solve it? If it is not correct then try to correct the question and give a hint to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: The exponential of a square matrix is again a square matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponent of a matrix is defined by a convergent infinite sum.

Use $\det e^A=e^{\text{Tr }A}$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: Using ur Hint, for zeros, i found that 
t.Tr(A)+(1-t)Tr(B)=0 
Tr(A)/Tr(B)=1-(1/t)
LHS is negative, and RHS will be negative for all values in (0,1). Hence 1) is correct. am i right?  where Tr denotes trace.

Comment: No, this means that $tr(tA+(1-t)B)=0$ and $f(t)=0$ for exactly one $t$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Daw : Trace is linear operator so why can't do that? Can you explain more about ur result?

Comment: @Chiranjeev_Kumar Here, $tTr(A) + (1-t)Tr(B)=0$ implies $t(Tr(B)-Tr(A))=Tr(B)$ so $t=\frac{Tr(B)}{Tr(B)-Tr(A)}$ and $Tr(B)-Tr(A)\ne 0$ (given). Therefore exactly one zero exist for $f(t)$.